# force raw packets to go through iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, dhcp, raw-sockets

When using raw sockets to create raw ethernet frames, the resulting packets are not traversing the iptables, even if the frames created represent valid ethernet + ip + upd packets. In my case this happens with the ISC-DHCP-client. I can understand why this happens and this is fine so far.

Thant being said, what **additional** infrastructure could I nevertheless put in place to get a chance to process those packets in iptables.

I'd be fine with stuff like (additional) virtual interfaces, bridges, or something like that. But so far I couldn't find the right combination of them.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in a previous project where I had to man-in-the-middle a TCP session inside a LAN. To do so, on my gateway laptop I needed to route incoming traffic to a local process running the MITM attack. I used iptables but of course it was not working since the communications between the 2 hosts inside the LAN was happening at L2 not triggering the iptables. After A LOT of struggling I solved it in this way:
I created a bridge between the 2 interfaces that the attacked hosts used for communicate (say eth0 and eth1). Then you can use ebtables ([man page ebtables](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/misc/ebtables-man.html)) which allows to force frames matching a specific rule to go through iptables. E.g in my case:

`ebtables −t broute −A BROUTING −i eth0 −p ipv4 −−ip−proto tcp --ip-dport 8009 −j redirect −−redirect−target DROP`

The above rule is basically saying that: frames coming into eth0, carrying TCP packets destined to port 8009, should be sent to iptables.

Quoting the man page:

> Making it DROP in the BROUTING chain will let the frames be routed.

If you want a good reference about the interaction iptables/ebtables, I used this one [ebtables/iptables](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html). Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion!
However, ebtables will not quite work, since I need to use iptable's `-j CLASSIFY --set-class 0000:0042` target

Comment: @MartinKeßler After the ebtables you can use whatever rule on the packet, also the one you wrote.